# Phusion Passenger is killing my process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

[As described here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_smart_spawning_gotcha_2_the_need_to_revive_threads), I'm detecting that I've been forked by Phusion Passenger, and revive a background thread that is aggregating some data that will eventually get packaged and sent to a remote server after a set amount of time.  But sometimes, before the thread wakes up from the sleep, the process disappears, and (according to my log messages, that report the PID when the thread wakes up), I never hear from it again.   Any way to control or prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating threads within a Passenger hosted process. If Passenger doesn't think your process is busy servicing requests, it is free to shut it down without warning. Those background threads should be used only in the course of your request processing.

What you want is a background job processing facility like [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to offload this.