# Can Phusion Passenger notify me that it's about to terminate my process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

[As described here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_smart_spawning_gotcha_2_the_need_to_revive_threads), Passenger will fork my process, and I'll need to revive my background thread.  I do that, and it usually works, but sometimes my process gets terminated before my background thread is finished.  All I'm doing on that background thread is queuing a bunch of data so I can send it more efficiently in a bigger chunk.  [I just asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729233/phusion-passenger-is-killing-my-process), but I have a new idea:  I'm wondering if I can register for a callback similar to this one:

```
PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|...
```

but instead of on the `:starting_worker_process` event, I want to get notified that my process is about to be terminated so I can quickly flush my buffer and get out.  Is there such an event?

Answer (score 1):

Kernel provides [#at_exit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit) which can be used for this.

```
at_exit do
  # Cleanup
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  I had that in place already, but it does not seem to get called under passenger.  In a stand-alone ruby app, it works perfectly.  I flush the buffers immediately, and all my data gets through.  Does Passenger actually kill my processes, or just put them to sleep?  I'll try looking for SIGKILL, etc.  Should I expect `at_exit` to trigger when I get a `kill -9`?

Comment: Passenger will actually kill off processes after they've been inactive for long enough, though I'm not sure which mechanism it uses to do so. `kill -9` will send SIGKILL, which cannot be caught or handled. Have you considered using something like a journal file to recover from unexpected terminations?

Answer (score 0):

From Passenger's source code, looks like there is an event called `:stopping_worker_process`. I haven't not tested this though.